# Intuition behind the definition of line curve

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Length_of_a_curve)

If $X = \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, and if $\gamma$: $[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an injective and continuously differentiable function, then the length of $\gamma$ is defined as the quantity

$$\text{Length}(\gamma) = \int_{a}^{b}|\gamma'(t)|dt \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

The length of a curve is independent of the parametrization $\gamma$

In particular, the length $s$ of the graph of a continuously differentiable function $y = f(x)$ defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$ is

$$s = \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1 + [f'(x)]^{2}} dx \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

My 2 questions are :

- what is the meaning of the $df$ sign on top of the equal sign of the wikipedia equation (which I couldn't reproduce here)
- what is the intuition behind the second equation (equation (2))

Comment: I think that here the "df" just stands for "definition". Equation (1) is defining what is meant by the "length of $\gamma$".

Comment: (2) is just an application of (1). (1) is the important equation. A curve is just a set of points {$(x,y)$}in xy space. For the curve in equation (2), the set of points is {$(x,f(x))$}. A parameterization is just a mapping, but whose domain is thought of as "outside/separate from" the xy plane. So an element $t$ from some random "t-domain" outputs into the xy plane. Therefore to parameterize a curve, the set of points {$(x,y)$}, you need some sort of mapping {$(x=g(t), y = h(t))$} often written as {$(x(t), y(t))$}. For the curve in (2), you parameterize {$(x, f(x))$} by (x = g(t) = t, y = f(t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Df is the shorthand for "definition" here. You might have seen the sign $:=$ before.

The intuition behind the second equation is as follows. For small enough change $dx$, function $f$ changes by amount $df$. The length can then be approximated by Pythagora's theorem to be $\sqrt{dx^2+df^2}$. If you want the full length, sum over all the small changes to get $\int_a^b \sqrt{dx^2+df^2}$. Finally:

$$\int_a^b \sqrt{dx^2+df^2} = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2}\, dx = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx.$$

Of course, you can just use the definition of the length of the curve as given in the article if you choose to parametrize the graph as $\gamma(t) = (t,f(t))$ and so $\gamma'(t) = (1,f'(t))$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Ennar. It's getting clearer. Just one more question: you can transform the first expression before the first equal sign by dividing everything by $dx^{2}$, correct? If so doesn't that also affect the expression on the other side of the equal sign, namely $s$. And sorry if it's a silly question but I'm not a math guy. Isn't there one more $dx$ at the end of the first expression after "Finally", before the equal sign? Thank you very much again!

Comment: It's not dividing by $dx^2$, it's just that $\sqrt{dx^2+df^2} = \sqrt{dx^2(1+(df/dx)^2)} = dx\sqrt{1+f'(x)}$. But don't take it too literally, it's far from formal proof... but you asked for intuition.

Comment: ok @Ennar thank you